# PHP - check proper text with preg_match in form ( a-z,A-Z,0-9)

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need check user name with `preg_match` to be from `a-z` , `A-Z` ,or `0-9` only. First I use `ereg` but I find its deprecated so I use `preg_match`.

But it dosn't work. Any idea ?

```
$test = "test";

if (preg_match("/^[_a-zA-Z0-9]+$/", $test)){
    echo"account generated" ;

}else{
    echo "Please write proper username";
}
```

Comment: Why `!` i think you want the opposite? Now if you have a `-` in the name it's generated ?!

Comment: Now it works? Or what doesn't work? Describe it more.

Comment: It works. I don't see any problems

Comment: Its work now , but I need understand this code , why I should write _ before a-z & and what mean +$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `!` in your regex and it will work!

Regex:

```
^[_a-zA-Z0-9]+$/
```

`^` assert position at start of the string
`[_a-zA-Z0-9]+` match a single character present in the list below
Quantifier: `+` Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
`_` the literal character _
`a-z` a single character in the range between a and z (case sensitive)
`A-Z` a single character in the range between A and Z (case sensitive)
`0-9` a single character in the range between 0 and 9
`$` assert position at end of the string

Also a good website to test your regex: [regex101](http://regex101.com) (Also got that information from there)

And if you are learning regex a [cheat sheet](http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/) is always good :D

Comment: @Rizier123 i didn't find any `!` symbol in his regex.

Comment: @AvinashRaj See the comments(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27646946/php-check-proper-text-with-preg-match-in-form-a-z-a-z-0-9/27647004?noredirect=1#comment43711650_27646946)!